# How to stop router matching on first match in ambiguous routing in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

In my project i have routes for different pages. I want to stop the execution on first route matching. My route.js file have this code

```
export default [
    {
        exact: true,
        component: Home,
        path: "/"
    },
    {
        exact: true,
        component: ShopingCart,
        path: "/shopingcart"
    },
    {
        exact: true,
        component: LinkChanger,
        path: "/:pathname"
    }
];
```

And i have a file which uses these route.js file

```
<Switch>
    <Router  history={history} >
        <div>
        {
             routes.map( (route, index) =>
             <Route key={index} exact={route.exact} path={route.path} component={(props)=><route.component {...props} isAuthed={true} />}/>)
        }
        </div>
    </Router>
</Switch>
```

When i change my link to /shopingcart. Firstly component ShopingCart is called and then LinkChanger. Even after using switch my second component LinkChanger is called.
Is their any way to stop the routers at first match.

Comment: Shouldn't be the `Switch` component wrapping the `Route` components instead of the `Router`?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `Switch` inside `Router` -

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        {
            routes.map( (route, index) =>
            <Route key={index} exact={route.exact} path={route.path} component={(props)=><route.component {...props} isAuthed={true} />}/>)
        }
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: should work now. `Switch` should be a direct descendant to `Router` & `Route` should be a direct descendant to `Switch` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Switch>
    <div>
    {
         routes.map( (route, index) =>
         <Route key={index} exact={route.exact} path={route.path} component={(props)=><route.component {...props} isAuthed={true} />}/>)
    }
 </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i replaced div by switch

```
<Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
        {
            routes.map( (route, index) =>
            <Route key={index} exact={route.exact} path={route.path} component={(props)=><route.component {...props} isAuthed={true} />}/>)
        }
        </Switch>
</Router>
```